# Solving linear algebra equality (gradient-based optimization)

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, optimization, machine-learning

**Context:**

I am reading the paper "Gradient-based meta-learning with learned layerwise metric and subspace" ([arxiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.05558#:%7E:text=Gradient%2DBased%20Meta%2DLearning%20with%20Learned%20Layerwise%20Metric%20and%20Subspace,-Yoonho%20Lee%2C%20Seungjin&text=Gradient%2Dbased%20meta%2Dlearning%20methods,gradient%20descent%20during%20meta%2Dtesting.)), and am having some trouble with how one of the equalities on page 5.

The authors state the following (where bold font denotes a matrix and non-bold font denotes a vector):

\begin{equation}
y = \boldsymbol{TW}x = \boldsymbol{A}x
\end{equation}

They then go on to say that their new learning rule update is given as:

\begin{equation}
y_{new} = \boldsymbol{T}(\boldsymbol{T}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A} - \alpha \nabla_{\boldsymbol{T}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}}\mathcal{L_T})x
\end{equation}

which they say is equal to the following:

\begin{equation}
y_{new} = y - \alpha (\boldsymbol{TT}^{\intercal})\nabla_{\boldsymbol{A}}\mathcal{L_T}x
\end{equation}

**Question:**

However I don't quite understand how this is derived, in particular I am unsure as to where the term $(\boldsymbol{TT}^{\intercal})\nabla_{\boldsymbol{A}}$ comes from. Can someone please give me some guidance on how to resolve this?

**My attempt:**

Here is my attempt, but I am unsure how to derive the RHS.

\begin{align}
y_{new} 
&= \boldsymbol{T}(\boldsymbol{T}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A} - \alpha \nabla_{\boldsymbol{T}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}}\mathcal{L_T})x \\
&= \boldsymbol{T}\boldsymbol{T}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}x - \alpha \boldsymbol{T}\nabla_{\boldsymbol{T}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}}\mathcal{L_T}x \\
&= \boldsymbol{I}y - \alpha \boldsymbol{T}\nabla_{\boldsymbol{T}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}}\mathcal{L_T}x \\
&= y - \alpha \boldsymbol{T}\nabla_{\boldsymbol{T}^{-1}\boldsymbol{A}}\mathcal{L_T}x \\
&= \dots \\
\end{align}

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: isn't it just a change of variable? T transpose is the Jacobian.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Yimin! Do you mind expanding on your answer a bit, as my linear algebra/vector calculus is not very good?

Comment: consider T as the transform mapping T^{-1} A=(b_ij) to A=(a_ij), then use the chain rule to find the derivatives with respect to entries in A.  Since a_ij = \sum_k t_ik b_kj, thus \partial_{b_kj} = \sum_i t_ik \partial_{a_ij}, this is equivalent to \nabla_{T^{-1}A} = T^t \nabla_{A} @Decadz